# Can't change default timezone for Airflow Webserver UI

Tags: airflow

I set both `default_ui_timezone` and `default_timezone` to `Asia/Tokyo`, but airflow webserver UI is still displaying UTC time. Is there any way to change UI timezone without enabling RBAC? Airflow version is `1.10.10`.

Comment: have you try to upgrade your airflow to > 2.0 . This feature is default in airflow UI https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/timezone.html

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, maybe it will help someone:

1. Find airflow location:

```
pip show apache-airflow | grep Location
Location: /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

2. Edit `utils/timezone.py` file:

```
# utc = pendulum.timezone('UTC')
from airflow.configuration import conf
try:
    tz = conf.get("core", "default_timezone")
    if tz == "system":
        utc = pendulum.local_timezone()
    else:
        utc = pendulum.timezone(tz)
except Exception:
    pass
```

3. Within the same file, edit `utcnow()`:

```
# dt = dt.datetime.utcnow()
d = dt.datetime.now()
```

4. Edit `utils/sqlalchemy.py`:

```
# utc = pendulum.timezone('UTC')
try:
    tz = conf.get("core", "default_timezone")
    if tz == "system":
        utc = pendulum.local_timezone()
    else:
        utc = pendulum.timezone(tz)
except Exception:
    pass
```

5. Edit `airflow/www/templates/admin/master.html`:

```
// var UTCseconds = (x.getTime() + x.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
var UTCseconds = x.getTime();

// "timeFormat":"H:i:s %UTC%",
"timeFormat":"H:i:s",
```